# virtual address to physical address convertion in Linux user space

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am able to convert virtual address to physical address mapping in kernel space ( root user). I have reused the code of the tool provided [here](http://www.eqware.net/Articles/CapturingProcessMemoryUsageUnderLinux/index.html)

I want to do the same conversion in user space . Is it possible in user space (non root user ) ?

The above tool use /proc/pid/maps and /proc/pid/pagemap files in kernel mode,

EDIT :
After receiving comments, here is my updated questions.

I want to convert virtual address to physical address in non-root privilege user, and after finding the physical address, later I will use it to find mapping to L2 cache set. **My task is to find out where is my data loaded into L2 cache.**

Do I need to write a kernel module which will take user virtual address and will return physical address ? If so, any link in that direction will be great help.

Is phys_addr = virt_to_phys(virt_addr); correct option ? Also unable to understand how to use it/call it from my program ?

Comment: When would you want to do this?  It's not like you can use the physical address in any place.

Comment: I guess that @bholanath wants to write code in the style of a microkernel operating system. As Linus Torvalds pointed out in the 1990s, this is a bad idea.

Comment: "user space" doesn't mean "non root user". The kernel/userspace division is about more fundamental stuff than the division between privileged and unprivileged processes.

Comment: This will be further complicated by [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) scrambling you'll nowadays find on almost any system (although you could turn it off).

Comment: Thank you all. @ Wumpus, yes I am talking about unprivileged  user. @gnometorule , I have disabled ASLR also.@ Nathan , I am using the physical address in the remaining part of my program.